# PRevent Windows 10 Shutdown as long as process is still running

Tags: windows, vmware, shutdown, desktop, group-policy

I habe a Windows 10 host system that runs a VMWare Workstation virtual machine. I would like to prevent shutdown or logoff on that host system as long as the VM is still running, preferrably activating the VMWare Workstation process instead.

I tried adding a btach file to the logoff or shutdown script using gpedit, but the probem with that approach is that the system already loses its desktop and gos to the "Shutdown screen" instead.

What I need is to interrupt the shutdown process just before I lose my desktop and to be able to still interact with the active desktop session, i.e. display a message box.

Is it possible to completely stop an initiated shutdown process in Windows 10 at all?

Comment: Why don’t you just, enable, the *Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands* group policy?

Comment: Microsoft got fed up with various ill-behaved programs interrupting the shut down process, sometimes indefinitely, so Windows no longer allows it.